# ePass2003Auto Integration in Linux

Tags: smartcard, xfreerdp

I am trying to integrate **[ePass2003Auto](http://www.ftsafe.com/product/epass/epass2003)** USB token in Ubuntu-14.04, so that I can pass this device for `xfreerdp` connection.

I followed [gooze](http://www.gooze.eu/howto/smartcard-quickstarter-guide/opensc-installation-under-gnu-linux) instructions for ePass2003 token.

But when I execute these commands after running `pcscd` daemon, I get nothing.

```
# opensc-tool --list-drivers
Configured card drivers:
  ...
  entersafe        entersafe
  epass2003        epass2003      <--- There it is!
  rutoken          Rutoken driver
  ...

# opensc-tool --list-readers
No smart card readers found.
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. NetVista Full Width Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 096e:080a Feitian Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I connect the device, it also mount CD-Rom, containing windows executable. 
So I tried `usb_modeswitch` with following config file:

```
DefaultVendor=  0x096e
DefaultProduct= 0x080a

TargetVendor=   0x096e
TargetProduct=  0x0807
```

Though, I am missing the `messagecontent` line for this config file.

Any idea, how can I make this device to work in Linux (Ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 2):

I just added this device on [the list of devices for my CCID driver](https://ccid.apdu.fr/ccid/shouldwork.html#0x096E0x080A).

Use the current git version of the [`supported_readers.txt`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ccid/blob/master/readers/supported_readers.txt) file, (re)install the CCID driver and your device should be available by OpenSC.